# Why "Monotonicity" Hypothesis? (Koontz-Garboden)

Tags: syntax, morphology, morphosyntax

Should't it be "monodirectionality hypothesis"?

In my understanding, this is about the one-way that material/structure can be added to a sentence-while-generated, but never deleted. (Harley 2013 cites, next to this Monotonicity H. of Koontz-Garboden, Emonds' Structure Preserving Hypothesis)

Comment: Are you asking why the technical term is called "monotonicity?

Comment: yes exactly that is what I question

Comment: It’s an established term that means precisely that.

Comment: Do you have any idea who first coined the term? Mathematics seems to eschew historical references to first uses of terms.

Comment: Lexical-functional grammar has a similar concept. In mathematics, if a function is monotonic on some interval (a, b), it means that either f(c) >= f(d) for all c, d OR or f(c) <= f(d) for all c, d in the interval (a, b) with c > d. Linguistics takes this concept but discards the second statement in the disjunction (f(c) <= f(d)).

Comment: too bad then linguistics deals with Tone, too

Comment: I never associated tone with monotonicity until you mentioned it, haha.